# Ubuntu 22.04 - Intel X550 - Run a pre-up command to set ethtool network interface parameters at startup

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking, intel, ifconfig

Following the question at:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406445/ubuntu-22-04-server-intel-x550-advertised-speed-not-correct
I need to run a command at startup so that the necessary changes are permanent. From the Intel drivers documentation (https://downloadmirror.intel.com/727507/readme.txt),
the command is:

```
pre-up ethtool -s <ethX> advertise 0x1800000001028 || true
```

I tried to write the command in various files, without success.

Where should I write it ?

Edit 1:
Following Anton Danilov's answer, I did not find how to set up a solution with sytemd.link, but I found a different way by creating a service in

```
/etc/systemd/system
```

as explained here:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=262075

It works, but is it the optimal way for Ubuntu 22.04 (the link above is a solution for archlinux and is from 2018) ?
If no, could someone please provide a complete working solution for Ubuntu Server 22.04 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Ubuntu Server 22.04 I am going to guess you are using `netplan` with `systemd-networkd` as the "renderer".

You could try putting a script in `/etc/networkd-dispatcher/configuring.d`.  E.g.

```
mkdir -p /etc/networkd-dispatcher/configuring.d/
install -m 0755 /dev/null /etc/networkd-dispatcher/configuring.d/x550
cat <<EOF > /etc/networkd-dispatcher/configuring.d/x550
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ethtool -s <ethX> advertise 0x1800000001028 || true
EOF
```

I chose `configuring.d` based on the [Netplan hook table mapping](https://netplan.io/faq/#use-pre-up%2C-post-up%2C-etc.-hook-scripts).  Another state might work better.

**other links**

- https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/networkd-dispatcher.8.html
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/networkctl.1.html
- https://gitlab.com/craftyguy/networkd-dispatcher

Answer (score 0):

The recent versions of ubuntu use the [netplan](https://netplan.io/) network configuration tool. Unfortunately it lacks the setting of the advertising of speed modes. So you can switch to usage of networkd directly without this wrapper.

For networkd you should edit the `.link` file and set the `Adevertise` option. See the `man systemd.link`.